# How to avoid poping up of phantomjs.exe window while launching the window application made in PyQT

Tags: javascript, java, json, django, phantomjs

I have created a Desktop Application in Python3.5 .It works fine . But when I converted .py file to .exe using PyInstaller PhantomJs a Black Screen pop up.
I want to hide that PhantomJs.exe black Screen.
**PhantomJS is a headless WebKit scriptable with a JavaScript API. It has fast and native support for various web standards: DOM handling, CSS selector, JSON, Canvas, and SVG.**
OS :- Windows10

def funcSearchKeyword(self):

```
try:
    self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()   #Opens PhantomJs browser Black Screen
    self.driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/")
    self.elem = self.driver.find_element_by_name("q")
    self.elem.clear()
    self.elem.send_keys(self.keyword)     # self.keyword -- a variable
    self.elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)



finally:
    print("Exception")
    self.driver.quit()
```